# Batch file not receiving the ERRORLEVEL from the python script it launches

Tags: python, batch-file, errorlevel

I have a batch file running a python script.
This python script always ends using `sys.exit(code)` no matter what, with code being an error code.
The batch file doesn't get my error code and instead always reads 0 with the following:

```
..\..\STS\Python\python.exe Version_code_ID.py %*  
echo Error level = %ERRORLEVEL%
```

This instalation of python is in 3.7.1.
I know for sure my python code exited with other codes than 0 thanks to my logger (and me voluntarily causing errors for testing purpose).
For example I had it exit with 1 and 12, both attempts resulting in getting 0 in the batch.

Just in case, here is also the python function I use to exit:

```
def exit(code):
    if(code > 0 ):
        log.error("The computing module will shutdown with the following error code : "+str(code))
    elif(code == 0):
        log.info("Execution sucessfull")
    log.info("STOP of VERSION_CODE_ID Computing Module")
    log.removeHandler(stream_handler)
    log.removeHandler(file_handler)
    stream_handler.close()
    file_handler.close()
    sys.exit(code)
```

log is just the name of my logging.handlers logger.

Any idea what might be causing this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't call a function `exit` as there is a built-in one with already that name...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the bulk of my python script was in this try clause:

```
try:
    #All of my code
except SystemExit:
    ()
except Exception as ex:
    fun.log.error('ERROR: Unknown exception: ' + repr(ex))
```

I originally added the

```
except SystemExit:
    ()
```

because I thought SystemExit showing-up as an "exception" in the console was a problem, but it's not.
In short the solution was to remove that `except`.
The reason seem to be that catching the `systemExit`, as the name implies, doesn't let it get sent to the batch, which then believes no error code was sent.

Surprisingly for me `except Exception as ex:` doesn't catch the `systemExit` made by `sys.exit()`. That's great in my case since I still need it to log unknown exceptions.